# how to disable query from beeline results

Tags: apache-hadoop, hive

I am occuring a strange `hive`-client `beeline` behavior. 
In the outputed file with query results there is also a queary at the beggining and at the end. Is there any option to disable such behavior? I can't see such option in the `beeline -help`

```
-bash-4.2$ beeline -help
Usage: java org.apache.hive.cli.beeline.BeeLine 
   -u <database url>               the JDBC URL to connect to
   -n <username>                   the username to connect as
   -p <password>                   the password to connect as
   -d <driver class>               the driver class to use
   -i <init file>                  script file for initialization
   -e <query>                      query that should be executed
   -f <exec file>                  script file that should be executed
   --hiveconf property=value       Use value for given property
   --hivevar name=value            hive variable name and value
                                   This is Hive specific settings in which variables
                                   can be set at session level and referenced in Hive
                                   commands or queries.
   --color=[true/false]            control whether color is used for display
   --showHeader=[true/false]       show column names in query results
   --headerInterval=ROWS;          the interval between which heades are displayed
   --fastConnect=[true/false]      skip building table/column list for tab-completion
   --autoCommit=[true/false]       enable/disable automatic transaction commit
   --verbose=[true/false]          show verbose error messages and debug info
   --showWarnings=[true/false]     display connection warnings
   --showNestedErrs=[true/false]   display nested errors
   --numberFormat=[pattern]        format numbers using DecimalFormat pattern
   --force=[true/false]            continue running script even after errors
   --maxWidth=MAXWIDTH             the maximum width of the terminal
   --maxColumnWidth=MAXCOLWIDTH    the maximum width to use when displaying columns
   --silent=[true/false]           be more silent
   --autosave=[true/false]         automatically save preferences
   --outputformat=[table/vertical/csv2/tsv2/dsv/csv/tsv]  format mode for result display
                                   Note that csv, and tsv are deprecated - use csv2, tsv2 instead
  --truncateTable=[true/false]    truncate table column when it exceeds length
   --delimiterForDSV=DELIMITER     specify the delimiter for delimiter-separated values output format (default: |)
   --isolation=LEVEL               set the transaction isolation level
   --nullemptystring=[true/false]  set to true to get historic behavior of printing null as empty string
   --help                          display this message
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the option `--silent=True`.

Comment: `True` or `true` or it doesn't matter?

Comment: It does not work for me for Hive 1.0.0

Comment: But the documentation states it works for Hive 1.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

It really does not work. I am using :
Apache Hive (version 3.1.3000.7.1.9.0-387)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 3.1.3000.7.1.9.0-387)

And the options --silent=true or --silent=True does not work on command line
I have tried them many times and with different configurations; they have never worked for me.